# Variable 'x' stores 256bit binaries & occupies 256bits. Now, transmit 'x' in less than 256bits, but at receiver I must get back exact 256 bits of 'x'

Tags: image, matlab, compression, communication

x = 1001010010100; % say, 256 bit binaries

% transmit above data in less than 256 bits

% At receiver, I must get back, all 256 bits of x

% maximum allowed size to transmit is 256 bits or 32 bytes

Comment: x is in {0,1}^256, any other assumption on x?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no constraints on the 256 bits, then it will take 256 bits to transmit.  It cannot be compressed in all cases.  End of story.

Comment: I tried several ways. I couldn't make it less than 256 bits. I was just curious to know, if there were any possibilities/alternatives (which I might have not have known). Anyways, thank you